# use Admob and run ads without launching app on playstore

Tags: android, performance, admob

Can i use Admob and apply ads on my application and start earning or it is necessary to upload you application to play store for making money from it? what if i upload it on some different plat form?

Comment: I hope you are saying instead of play store you can upload to amazon store etc. yes there also your application will earn in the same manner

Comment: Yes, Like for the playstore i have to signup for a developer account which cost $25 and some platforms like huawei offer such account for free publishing application. If i use admob and publish my application on huawei store or some other free publishing platform would that work? @ramanavv

Answer (score 0):

You can publish your app on any platform. Playstore or Appstore to start earning. But publishing you App is must.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Like for the play store you already signed up for a developer account [$25] and As you know about some other platforms like Huawei, Amazon Store offering such accounts for free and publishing applications in these stores and If You use AdMob and any platform will work after installing basically play store doesn't matter. It depends on integration in your application.